# How to hide the display of background HDR map, but save hdri's work for lighting in three.js?

Tags: javascript, php, three.js, hdr

I repeat this example in my code:

https://threejs.org/examples/?q=RGBELoader#webgl_loader_gltf

Source:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_gltf.html#L53

HDRI lighting works great. But i cant hide hdr map from background. Is there way to do this? To leave this hdri lightning and set a custom color for background.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand what you are trying to achieve here, you want that instead of seeing the passageway photo in the background you just want a solid color background?

Comment: yes, solid color instead of hdr on background

Answer (score 5):

Using the example you provided, and assuming you want to keep the reflections of the photo on the helmet but remove the photo from the background, all you have to do is remove (or comment out) the following [line](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_gltf.html#L122):

```
scene.background = cubeGenerator.renderTarget;
```

This will remove the photo from the background which will then display as the default color (black), as you can see from this screenshot:

[image]